# Why js_sys::Atomics operations require value of type i32?

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen

I'm trying to use `SharedArrayBuffer` in rust. I want to accumulated output from n workers in part of sab. As i found out i'm constrained to int array types, but my data stored as floats. I'm using `Atomics::add(&rc2, idx as u32, k)` where k is my float transformed into i32. I'm receiving some garbage in each of the described approaches (when im trying to read through float32 view from filled sab). What i've tried: 1) use `to_ne_bytes + i32::from_be_bytes` on my float and then reassemble it as i32 2) use `std::mem::transmute::<f32, i32>(v);` 3) use to_bits / cast to u32 / from_bits / cast to i32 4) look up implementation in js sys github repo (here https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/blob/master/crates/js-sys/src/lib.rs), but there is seems to be only some bindings to external code, i dont understand where this code located so i would be able to check why Atomic add wants i32 and what it does with it. Thanks!

Comment: The [`Atomics.add()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Atomics/add) method in JavaScript for which this is but a binding only works for integer types. Since float values are stored and add in different way compared to ints no kind of `transmute()` trickery will help you. You need to accumulate the output without using atomics.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @HHK , what is puzzling me is there multiple kinds of views available, which are supported for atomic operations (like u8, u16) but all Atomic functions in js sys docs require i32, i thought there is some internal magic going on which will allow to perform add on arbitrary types